# Get Azure VM Overview / Monitoring data via powershell or azure cli

Tags: powershell, azure, command-line-interface

When we login to azure portal and have a look at any resource like VM, we will see some monitoring data in Overview section of each resource which shows us charts for 30 days. (CPU average, network in/out etc)

My requirement is to not make any changes to azure resources via portal or cli. But i am rather looking for a powershell / azure cli command which will pull all this data from azure to my local machine for some analysis.

I am looking for VM, Web apps and Azure SQL to start with.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of analysis? Why aren’t you using something like OMS Inisights & Analytics to capture, chart, and alert on this data?

Comment: I am trying to do some other analysis on this data and would like it to code it out myself. I have around 200 VMs plus other resources and i am trying to code a personalized dashboard around few analysis myself. Have seen all the azure and other 3rd party tools and none meet my criteria. IF i get just get this data via cli or powershell, i can do rest myself in no time.

Comment: i think i got what i needed.  az monitor metrics list --resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxx --metric-names "Percentage CPU" --time-grain "PT1M" >> PercentageCpuData.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, we can use CLI 2.0 to get the metric data:

```
az monitor metrics list --resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Micros‌​oft.Compute/virtualM‌​achines/xxxx --metric-names "Percentage CPU" --time-grain "PT1M" >> PercentageCpuData.txt
```

Also we can use Azure PowerShell command `Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition` to get metrics.

Here are the metrics for Azure VM:

```
PS D:\testdata> (Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId $id).name

Value                     LocalizedValue
-----                     --------------
Percentage CPU            Percentage CPU
Network In                Network In
Network Out               Network Out
Disk Read Bytes           Disk Read Bytes
Disk Write Bytes          Disk Write Bytes
Disk Read Operations/Sec  Disk Read Operations/Sec
Disk Write Operations/Sec Disk Write Operations/Sec
CPU Credits Remaining     CPU Credits Remaining
CPU Credits Consumed      CPU Credits Consumed
```

Then we can use the value to get other metrics:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $id -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput -MetricNames "Network in"
```

Here [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258409/unable-to-access-guest-metrics-using-get-azurermmetric/46274028#46274028) about you, please refer to it.

By the way, difference about Azure Host metrics and Guest metrics, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316154/azure-host-vs-guest-metrics-for-vm/46316778#46316778).

Comment: not able to +1 it but can confirm that the above approached worked for me.

Comment: We can follow this link to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, thank you:)